# Programming language of QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

For the functions of the field calculator in QGIS, in which programming language does it have the most parallels?

In ArcGIS field calculator you have to decide between VBScript, JavaScript and Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create custom functions in the QGIS field calculator using Python:

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/custom_python_functions.html

But the field calculator itself is not in any specific language. Although closest would be SQL.

Comment: You are right, the most operaters and functions are nearly the same in postgresql. Thks.